# Copying contents of a file into another in File Handling

Tags: while-loop, file-handling, readline, with-statement, continue

I want to copy the Python Scripts ignoring the comments in a code to another file. I have tried the below code but its copying all the lines of the code including comments. Please let me know how to rectify it. I am a newbie in Python Programming.

```
with open("essays.txt",'rb') as f1:
    with open("myfile.txt",'wb') as f2:
        while True:
            buf=f1.readline()
            if len(buf)!=0:
                if buf[0]=='#':
                    continue
                else:
                    f2.write(buf)
                    
            else:
                break
print("File Copied")
```

The above is copying all the contents of file1 into file2 including the comments which is not required in the output.

Answer (score 0):

I have checked your code is working when the first character is #. Now imagine if there are spaces or tabs at the beginning, then your code will not work.

Please try the below code, strip white spaces and tabs from the left of the string and then check for the first character.

```
    with open("createEntitiesFromDB.py",'rb') as f1:
            with open("myfile.txt",'wb') as f2:
                    while True:
                            buf=f1.readline()

                            if len(buf)!=0:
                                    buf2 = buf.lstrip()
                                    if len(buf2)!=0:
                                            if buf2[0]=='#':
                                                    continue
                                            else:
                                                    f2.write(buf)
                                    else:
                                            f2.write(buf)
                                    
                            else:
                                    break
    print("File Copied")
```